# Android Tabs problem

Tags: android

I have used 2 tabs in my app.

when i click on first tab it is showing an list view( default) and when i click on any particular item in list view it is taking me to the next activity to display the selected data. Here when i click on tab again i want that i should go to the listview screen which is default screen.

but nothing happens on clicking the tab but when i press the back button i m going back on the screen. but i want to go to home list view screen on tab click,

pls help me in this case...

Comment: it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong when we can't see what you're doing. Posting parts of your code will probably help...

Comment: Post up some of your code, and accept some answers on your previous questions, that will get you better answers here :)

Answer (score 0):

You say you start a new Activity. This one can not call the first Activity where you have the tabs. Am I right that your new activity just shows the two tabs as well?

What you could do is the following:

1. In the second Activity react to the onclick of the tab. When clicked call finish() to close the Activity.

I am pretty sure, that you don't need to do the following. But I write it, if you need it for something in the future :).

1. In the first Activity call the next through startActivityForResult(...)
2. In the first Activity overwrite the onActivityResult method. there you can switch to the tab with the list.

Comment: Hi Thanks Patrick for the reply..yes you r right my next activity shows two tabs as well. because it is in activity group. Patrick hw can i implement?

Comment: i would recommend redesigning the app. two activities showing the same tabs? the behaviour with the back button is how i would it expect. if you look at twitter or tweetdeck than you see listviews as well. when you click it brings you to a new activity. you go back by clicking on the back button. is pretty common on android. and everyone understands that. or should.